# Python re.groups doesn't show all the subgroups

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like `'234 3452789 23 901234 ...'`. I want to extract all the numbers. I wrote the following regular expression:

```
s = '234 3452789 23 901234'
expr = r'^\s*(\d+\s*)+$'
e = re.match(expr, s)
print e.groups()
```

I expect to see a tuple containing all the numbers, but actually this code prints the latest number only:

```
('901234',)
```

**Question**: What's wrong in my code, and how to fix it?

**P.S.** The code below works well, but I want to parse strings with any number of substrings

```
expr = r'^\s*(\d+\s*)(\d+\s*)(\d+\s*)(\d+\s*)$'
e = re.match(expr, s)
print e.groups()
```

Comment: why don't u try `r'\d+'` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj There are spaces.

Comment: @AvinashRaj u mean re.findall(r'\d+', s)? Actually I can, but I wrote here a bit simplified example. I am interested why the function `e.groups()` works so. I didn't expect such behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** use `findall()`:

```
>>> s = '234 3452789 23 901234'
>>> re.findall('\d+', s)
['234', '3452789', '23', '901234']
```

---

> I expect to see a tuple containing all the numbers, but actually this code prints the latest number only:
>
> ```
> ('901234',)
> ```
>
> Question: What's wrong in my code, and how to fix it?

That's how `match()` works, you can't do anything about it. A regular expression containing one group (like yours) you return only one group. Specifying a `+` or a `*` to the right of the group is *the* way for getting only the last match. It works this way by design.

If you really want to go with `match()`, the [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) third-party module provides the `captures` and `capturesdict` methods that do what you want. However it's not part of the standard library.

Comment: Ok, how to collect all the matches into the group tuple (using my approach)? Is this possible?

Comment: @MaksimSurov: I'm not sure what you mean. You can't use `match()` to obtain a variable number of groups.

Comment: I can explain. The problem of your solution is it matches a string like '234w3452789blabla23 901234'. But it hasn't to.

Comment: @MaksimSurov: in that case you have to *validate* the string with `match()`, then *extract* the values using `findall()`. Or you can use the `captures` feature of [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). Or you can build your own parser.

Comment: The actual regular expression looks like '^\s*(very difficult pattern)\w+(the same difficult pattern)\w+...$', so I thought that I can verify and extract all the entries by `re.match().groups()`. So, I wanted to extract from a file the only necessary lines. I regret that my solution is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

my simple two cents, to answer your actual question... why use regex and why not use

```
[int(grp) for grp in s.split() if grp.isdigit()]
```

This splits the string into groups based on the space separator, iterates through the list of separated groups, checks if it is a number or not if so pushes that group into list. The check is to make sure that we only push back numbers.

Its (a) faster

```
python -m timeit -s "import re" "[int(grp) for grp in re.findall('\d+','234 3452789 23 901234')]"
>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.14 usec per loop

python -m timeit "[int(grp) for grp in '234 3452789 23 901234'.split() if grp.isdigit()]"
>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.99 usec per loop
```

and (b) based on what i read from multiple discussions here... predictable and easy to understand. I tried once explaining the subtleties between `re.findall`, `re.search`, `re.split`, `re.finditer`. Took me some time. My recommendation try to avoid `re` if you can.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Assumed its simple enough...we split the s over " ". Check each split group whether its a number or not and if it is convert that into and int  hence  returning a list of int.  If you are trying to solve the problem of convrting a string of numbers to int it doesnt get simpler than this... if you are trying to find an answer to how re.match works as compared to re.findall (suggested by few ) then I am not answering your question.

Comment: Also you could try timing it and see if it runs faster for your actual string... hint it should

Comment: Please don't explain it to me, edit your answer to improve it's quality and to explain it to everyone who has the same problem.

Comment: I belive the code is self explanatory... and it says simple twice..is there some thing in particular u are looking for?

Comment: I'm not really interested in the question, it just came up in the _low quality_ review queue. Looking at the other answers here it seems to me that your answer is not the first one that comes into mind, so you should at least add why to choose your answer. And what is simple to a professional may be incomprehensible for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with your first code?

`r'^\s*(\d+\s*)+$'` regex should match all the digit or space characters from start and captures only the last digit characters and the following zero or more spaces since you're repeating the capturing group one or more times.

For example, `'(1+)'` and `(1)+` are doing the same match but both captures different set of 1's. First regex captures all the matched 1's where the second regex captures only the last 1 exists in each  single match.

`matchobj.groups()` would return a tuple of all characters which are captured by each single group.

Answer (score 0):

It matches the entire string due to `^...$`, and only captures the last match for the `(...)`. I assume it wasn't a strong enough use case, although someone filed an [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue7132) about allowing multiple matches to accumulate in a list.

The indexing of `groups()` is based on the layout of capturing groups in your regex, and not the string it's used on, so you wouldn't get a group for each distinct occurrence anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The $ towards the end would make it choose the last section only

Comment: without the `$`, it captures the same last number.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the ^ too.
Plus, you'll need to use findall() and change the regex to expr = r'\s*(\d+)+'